# Solar panel voltage drop

Tags: solar-cell, 12v

I'm having a problem with my solar panels.
I'm running a gecko 57l fridge out of a 100ah deep cycle battery with an 160w portable solar panels.
The system works fine and it outputs 13.7v to charge the battery but when I turn the fridge on the voltage drops and it stops to charge the battery.
I have tried to leave the panels on full sun with the fridge on during 12 hours and the battery just looses voltage and it doesn't charge at all.
I have made a video to explain
https://youtu.be/Ed7iX0H7ubQ[image][image][image]

Comment: Hello Gonçalo welcome to EE sx, we will need more detail to solve this, how is the circuit wired? do you have the panel directly connected to the battery and the fridge? do you have a solar charger/regulator?

Comment: What is the power demand of the fridge? Aslo what is its starting load?

Comment: Have you looked at the video he provided?

Comment: @EdinFifić:  No, I didn't watch the video.  The question should stand on its own, without the video.  Facts should be written into the question.  A video should only be there for things that words can't capture well.  Power rating of the fridge and such things should be written out.  They are simple facts.

Comment: The fridge is connected directly to the battery, I have a charge controller. The fridge as 55w so at max it should consume 4.58 amps I have checked and it consumes 3. As for the panels they are only outputting 4.4 amps at max sunlight... being that both are wired in parallell they should output 8.8 amps I'm I wrong assuming one of them might be dead ?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please draw a block diagram how you connected everything.

Comment: We really want a schematic of the connections, not huge photographs and a link which you claim to be to a relevant video. You say you get 13.7V out of the panels in sunlight, but what is the current at 13.7V? What is the battery voltage when you have left the panels for 12hrs in the sun? Have you measured current at any point?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way that is an 80 Watt panel unless the label is from a different panel than the front pictures. 40 Watts maybe. State of the art for an affordable 6x6 inch solar cell is about 5W; you have 9 of them giving a maximum likely power of 45W - even less if they are a couple of years old, as efficiency has crept up from 15-16% to about 20%.

Measure the actual short circuit current of each panel : I bet it's just short of 2.5A. Given half the power you are claiming makes the observed behaviour close to what would be expected.

As for connecting the fridge : the load output of a cheap  charge controller will most likely trip when the fridge starts, due to the motor starting current surge, so connecting it across the battery is the most practical approach.

Comment: But it has the CE mark of quality! :b seriously in tge video the panels appear much taller than wide.  I think they have a hinge and a handle, so the photos above seem to show half the panel.

Comment: Ah, I went back and looked at the video.  The two 40W panels are hinged together allowing the mfg to claim it's a single 80W panel.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think is wrong: you need to connect your inverter/fridge to the LOAD OUTPUT of your charge controller, which is the 2 contacts on the right, next to the battery connection, opposite of the solar panel input.

Here is the manual for your charge controller:
https://www.solorder.se/image/data/uploads/KLD1210.pdf
 It states that you need to connect the battery first, then the panel and then the load or else you could damage it.
You have been doing the opposite, the panel was always connected, and the battery was getting connected and disconnected, so it's possible it is damaged.

Comment: I have two panels connected in parallel, they have the following specifications which: pm 80Wp,  Voc 22.5V, Isc 4.8 A, Vmp 18.2V,  Imp 4.4A

Comment: Can you take a picture of them, front and back? Especially the label part needs to be readable. And post the pictures here, of course, in your original question.

Comment: Just did. Both have same specks . And to answer what you said the panels are charging the battery until the fridge (load) is connected.

Comment: Yes, I see the picture. Just now I can see that the cells are divided up into 4 parts to produce 4 times the voltage. I was suspecting your label was wrong. I am trying to figure out what's wrong, besides the cheapest charge controller you have.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Did you try connecting your inverter to the LOAD output of your charge controller? Because that's where it's supposed to go, and this way it might be confusing the controller.

Comment: I Bought a camper and it was what they had on it. The only thing I don't understand is why it charges the battery fine but when the fridge turns on it stops. Do you think it could be the charging controller ?

Comment: Just try connecting the inverter to the load output on the charge controller, and then we'll see if it works fine.

Comment: I have the charging controller connected to the battery, and the fridge is connected to the battery too no inverter is used as everithing is running on 12v

Comment: OK, then connect the fridge directly to the load output of the charge controller. Make sure you observe the polarity (+ and -)!

Comment: But like that doesn't it mean that it will not work when there is no sun ?

Comment: The controller can be set to output all the time (24h) or the set amount of time in hours after the sun goes down. So, it can provide output even while it is charging. Just try it.

Comment: But because I'm only conecting the solar during the day  I will not have the controller on during the night .

Comment: You mean, you disconnect the controller from the battery at night?

Comment: Yes the controller is actually fitted to the solar panels.

Comment: You need to install the controller next to the battery, keep it always connected to the battery, and connect the fridge to its load output (light bulb symbol), and use a longer cable between the controller and the panels and disconnect THAT one if necessary.

Comment: Just try it for now to see if it will charge while the fridge is running. I am trying to help you solve your problem which you asked about in your original question. You need to work with me if you want to solve it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean I didn't want to work with you. I'm just trying it and the same thing happens. The solar is charging the battery and as soon as I connect the load the voltage drops and it stops to charge the battery.

Comment: If I check it is only putting 4.4 amps maximum would that mean that one of the panels is dead. As I understand they are connected in parallel and if one has a maximum power current both of them would have 8.8 is that correct ?

Comment: That's only correct if it's between 10AM and 2PM, the Sun is shining bright (clear sky), and the panels are turned exactly towards the Sun. If any of those conditions are lacking, the current output will be reduced.

Comment: Yes when I checked it was 12 pm clear blue skies.  And max would be 4.4 amps

Comment: Then one of your panels is not connected or is faulty.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108847/discussion-on-answer-by-edin-fific-solar-panel-voltage-drop).

Answer (score 0):

I see two deal-killing problems here, in rough order of precedence.

## 1.  You've got a serious case of Chinese krappe

Let's start with the panel.  This is a model is [almost a Google-whack](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=vaspfold-1nt-lj&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).  The only places that sell it are eBay and [Sunyee](https://www.sunyee.com.au/products/new-12v-120w-160w-200w-250w-folding-solar-panel-mono-camping-power), which proves this product is ***made for eBay***.  This usually means "complete junk".   *But let's look at the panel's own numbers.*  Given the dimensions (folding out, nine 156mm square solar cells x 2 panels), the surface area of solar cells is 0.438 square metre.  Their test rig claims 1000 watts per square metre solarization and 16.8% efficiency.  By my math, 1000 x 0.438 x 0.168 = 73 watts.  These are believable numbers based on the tech available.  160 watts *is simply impossible*.  Another alarm is cost.  Sunyee sells these for $98Au or $63US. That would make the panels cost 39 cents a watt, *well under half the price of panels from [any](https://www.newegg.com/eco-worthy-l02p160-1-solar-panels/p/2NZ-000D-00049) [credible](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Renogy-160-Watt-12-Volt-Monocrystalline-Solar-Panel-for-RV-Boat-Back-Up-System-Off-Grid-Application-RNG-160D-SS/310023204) vendor*. **So this panel is a complete fraud**.

That's a big part of why you're not getting enough power out of it and think half the panel is dead.

Now we look at the charge controller.  This is a [$10 special](http://www.jawmall.com/10a-12-24v-solar-charge-controller-dual-usb.html) straight off [Alibaba](https://mppt.en.alibaba.com/product/60655706566-806314955/12V_24V_10_Amps_Solar_Voltage_Regulator_KLD1210.html), so don't get your hopes up.  Until it smokes, it's barely adequate for the panel you think you have, and plentiful for the panel you actually do have.

I'm concerned about the battery sizing, because it is the nature of lead-acid batteries that they take damage when discharged more than about 30%.  So that "120AH" battery is good for about 40AH on a daily basis.   The refrigerator appears to be a perfectly nice unit, but it'll need to be to last in a moving vehicle.

## 2. Big knowledge gaps

There's a major failure point on projects like this - and that is the limits of your knowledge.  The most frequent issue is a matter of sizing.  Too small a battery is the #1 issue, and too small a panel (though you didn't know it at the time) is #2.  Right now the battery is running full-tilt.  That is because the refrigerator has not chilled down yet, so it's running at 100% cycle.  Eventually it will reach target cool, and will cycle on and off.  We know that the solar panel isn't big enough to run the refrigerator and charge the battery too.  So you need to borrow energy from the battery to get the fridge to initial chill; at which point it will cycle "off" and then the solar panel will hopefully be able to replenish the battery during the off cycles.  See the sizing problem?

Remember we can't make a habit of letting that lead-acid battery fall below 70% or we'll cut years off its life.  So even if you had the solar capacity you thought you did, you don't (practically) have the battery you thought you did.  My rule of thumb for refrigerators is 1 KWH per day, or 80 AH per day.  Somewhat less for yours, hopefully.

Your fondness for the cheap is also complicating things. Will we ever really trust that charge controller?  And of course the solar panel doesn't have much juice.  You'll stop doing that once you get more experience, but *getting* the experience will involve failure.  It may be frustrating, but **don't quit**.  You will have to expand the panels, get a better controller, and probably upsize your battery.  That's how you learn.

## 3. Cable sizing

The last problem I see, that may or may not be a problem, is sizing of wire and cable.  12 volt systems are very vulnerable to voltage drop.  That is particularly true when the battery is far from the charge controller or the load.

Basically, battery, charge controller and major loads should be right next to each other.

It's OK to have a bit of a run to the solar panel, but this should be  heavy rated wire, not whatever random electronics grade cable that is in the video.  10 AWG / 6 mm is not excessive.  Don't buy thick wire from hobby/electronics sources; that will be prohibitive in cost. Use common wire sold for mains power applications, such as that used to connect ovens/stoves, water heaters, etc.